# Taylor Series Approximation and Remainder Estimation theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Choose an appropriate Taylor series and use the Remainder Estimation Theorem to approximate $\cos(15^\circ)$ to five decimal-place accuracy.

I started by finding the polynomial of $n=2$ of cos and then plugging in $\pi/12$ radians and solving for $P(\pi/12)$. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to actually apply the estimation theorem (alternating series remainder is enough):

$$\left|\cos(x)-\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right|<\frac{|x|^{2N+2}}{(2N+2)!}$$

Here, we want to set

$$\frac{(\pi/12)^{2N+2}}{(2N+2)!}<10^{-5}$$

whereupon you will find that $N\ge2$ will suffice.  That is,

$$\left|\cos(\pi/12)-\sum_{n=0}^2\frac{(-1)^n(\pi/12)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right|<10^{-5}$$